# Include .whl installation in requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, requirements.txt

How do I include this in the requirements.txt file?
For Linux:

```
pip install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu75/torch-0.1.12.post2-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl 
pip install torchvision
```

FOR MacOS:

```
pip install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch-0.1.12.post2-cp27-none-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl 
pip install torchvision
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [environment markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0496/):

```
http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu75/torch-0.1.12.post2-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl ; sys_platform == "linux"
http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu75/torch-0.1.12.post2-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl ; sys_platform == "linux2"
http://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch-0.1.12.post2-cp27-none-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl ; sys_platform == "darwin"
torchvision
```

(Double Linux entries: `linux2` for Python 2, `linux` for Python 3.)

Comment: Say I update a package and run pip freeze> requirements.txt. Now I will have to add them manually every time.

Comment: You can’t do any better if you depend on things not in PyPI. You should convince the torch guys to publish their wheels there.

Comment: @ChrisWarrick [actually, you can do better](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv)

Comment: @OrangeDog Meh, pipenv tries to do way too much.

Comment: Well it'll install a requirements.txt and then output a frozen one for you, with wheels, git links, env markers, etc. preserved.